# Hard proof concerning the periodicity of trigonometrical functions. Is that a challenge or just trivial

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, logic, alternative-proof, foundations

i want to know if exist or if you can develop or give me ideas of a proof to show that the least number for which sine is periodic is $2\pi$
$$\neg \{\exists n\in \mathbb{R} \wedge n < 2\pi:  \sin(x)=\sin(x+n)\}$$
$$\neg \{\exists n\in \mathbb{R} \wedge n < 2\pi:  \cos(x)=\sin(x+n)\}$$

Is not enough to proof it by definition of fundamental period, i am wondering for a proof that avoids definitions of certain properties (i am not avoiding properties, just definitions, in order to show that from the inner core of geometry and logic). Can we build trigonometry without the definition of fundamental period?

We are allowed to use ALL THE THEORY we know about, analysis, logic, model theory, geometry, combinatorics, even topology, if you want, we just may try to avoid if it`s possible the definition of the periodicity. If that is a just a definition then....

I am not taking out the rest of the axioms of geometry, i am just trying to figure out wether or not the periodicity of trigonometrical functions is an axiom; or you can use any axiom, property, theorem that do not depends on that fact to proof it. Off course, we could not use Fourier series because that theory depends mainly on the periodicity of those functions, if we go further, i think that the sine function depends integrally on the existence of a least bound of periodicity.

Thank you very much

Comment: @Lord_Farin ah you were faster

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault

Comment: If we are going to pick nits, what about $n=-2\pi$? But more seriously, what definition of the sine function is the starting point?

Comment: @Lord_Farin This is pointless here, but there are infinitely many orders on $\mathbb{C}$. As many as proper convex cones containing $0$. The lexicographic order, for instance, is pretty popular.

Comment: I want to know what does [logic] and [foundations] have to do with this?

Comment: $\sin(\pi/6)=\sin(\pi/6+\pi/6)$ where $\pi/2 < 2\pi$ but they are equal.

Comment: @julien I know; it was just a nonstandard way of pointing out a small mistake.

Comment: Well, i want to develop a proof using principia mathematica style, i'm just taking out an axiom, and i am asking if trigonometry, can be built as a consistent mathematical structure without that axiom. Note that i am also avoiding the graph of sine, because that lead us to a formal definition of sine, or a function, isn't that foundational enough?

Comment: user57, is for a random x, thank you anyway

Comment: You hopefully are aware that not mentioning definitions does not make a fundamental difference for the theory. The assertion you wrote above is _provable_ given a definition of the sine function. Or are you considering some model-theoretic structure with $\sin$ as a function symbol?

Comment: If you want a _Principia Mathematica_ style proof, you are going to have to be _extremely_ explicit about the axioms you are allowed to use.  What are your "axioms of trigonometry"?  Which is being taken out?  (I'm also sure @Asaf would appreciate being notified about your response.)

Comment: every axiom that you know minus the fact of the periodicity. For example, the axioms provided by I. Gelfand, in Trigonometry less the "fact" that sin(x)=sin(2\pi+x) for all x

Comment: For such questions it is extremely important to lay down the rules of the game precisely: What is "sin", what is "$\pi$", are we allowed to talk about continuity, and so on.

Comment: We are allowed to use ALL THE THEORY we know about, analysis, logic, model theory, geometry, combinatorics, even topology, if you want, we just may try to avoid if it`s possible the definition of the periodicity. If that is a definition then....

Comment: Every axiom that I know?  So the axioms "The periodicity of cosine is $2\pi$" and "$\sin \theta = \cos ( \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta )$" are allowed?

Comment: The periodicity of sine and cosine are not allowed,

Comment: Periodicity of $\tan$?;)

Comment: 't Seems you are misunderstanding what a "_Princ. Math._-style proof" is all about. The idea is to give a definite set of rules, and then use them to derive and formally found e.g. analysis, trigonometry etc. etc. by defining the corresponding notions in the limited language and showing that they agree with what we expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok at first I will say what definitions I use. 
\begin{align*}
\exp(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\\
\sin(x)&=\frac{1}{2i} \left(\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)\right)\\
\cos(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)\right)
\end{align*} 
In special with those definitions I get the so called euler forlmula:
$$\exp(ix)=\cos(x) +i \cdot \sin(x)$$
Taking a unit circle in the complex plane, one can see that $\cos(x)$ is the projection on the real axis of $\exp(ix)$, when $x$ is real.

For the next step we will need the functional equation of the exponential function

> $$\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\cdot \exp(y)$$

We prove this equation, for the proof we will need the binomial theorem and the cauchy product. 
At first we recall the Binomial Theorem 
$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k} $$ 
The cauchy product is a special way to multiply two series, when both series are absolut convergent. As our series is absolute convergent for all $x$ we will just write the cauchy product 
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right) \cdot \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\right)=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^k a_{k-n} b_n $$

With those informations 
\begin{align*}
\exp(A+B)&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}  (A+B)^j \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}  \sum_{k=0}^j \binom{j}{k} A^{j-k} B^k\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^j \frac{1}{(j-k)!}  A^{j-k}  \frac{1}{k!}
B^k\\
&=\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}  A^j\right) \cdot
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}  B^k \right)\\
&=\exp(A) \cdot \exp(B)
\end{align*}

> (I copied myself here, I made this proof for the matrixexponential function)

Now we look at 
\begin{align*}
\cos(x+y)+i\cdot \sin(x+y)&=\exp(i(x+y))\\
 &= \exp(ix) \cdot \exp(iy)\\
 &= (\cos(x)+i\sin(x)) \cdot (\cos(y)+i\sin(y))\\
 &= \cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y) + i (\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x))
\end{align*}

Looking only at the imaginary part we see that
$$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)$$

Another definition I use

> $\pi$ is the smallest positive zero of the $\sin$ function.

Now let's assume that 
$$\sin(n+x)=\sin(x)$$
for all $x$, then we have 
$$\sin(x+n)=\sin(x)\cos(n)+\sin(n)\cos(x)=\sin(x)$$
At first we look at the special case $x=0$, with the series above we know that 
$$0=0\cdot \cos(n)+ \sin(n)\cdot 1$$
Ok so we know that $\sin(n)=0$ must be true hence $n$ must be an integer multiple of $\pi$,
because else $0<n-\pi<\pi$ and 
$$\sin(n-\pi)=\sin(n)\cos(-\pi) + \sin(-\pi)\cos(n)=0$$
would be a smaller positive zero than $\pi$ in contradiction to that $\pi$ is the smallest positive zero.

Now we try if 
$$\sin(\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$$
\begin{align*}
\sin(\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})&= \sin(\pi)\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot \cos(\pi)\\
&=-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\\
&\neq \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})
\end{align*}
Hence $\pi$ can't be the period of $\sin$ and the next possible choice $2\pi$ must be the period.

Comment: Wow, that is a big step, i would beg you to complement your answer with Cauchy product and binomial product

Comment: For me is not clear why if sin(n)=0, n must be a multiple of $\pi$, is n an integer multiple?

Comment: We definied $\pi$ to be the smallest positive number such that $sin(x)=0$. If $n$ is not an integer multiple you have $\sin(n-\pi)=\sin(n) \cos(-\pi) + \sin(n) \cos(-\pi)=0$ but $\pi$ and $n$ are both zeroes of the sin function, and hence $\sin(n-\pi)$ would be a zero of the sin function and be smaller than $\pi$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, that proves that there can be no zero of $\sin$ between $\pi$ and $2\pi$, which is considerably weaker than the statement that $n$ must be a multiple of $\pi$. (It's also sufficient, though, once you show that $\pi$ isn't a period and $2\pi$ is).

Comment: @SebastianGriotberg updated my answer sry it took a bit longer

Comment: @PeterTaylor You can do the same with $\sin(n-k\pi)$ and get to the same conclusion can't you ?

Comment: Yes, once you first prove (e.g. by induction on $k$) that $\sin(k\pi) = 0$, but that takes you further out of your way. Surely it would be more straightforward to prove that $sin(2\pi) = 0$, then prove that $2\pi$ is the period (still a missing step - you need to show that $\cos(2\pi) = 1$!), and finally use that to show that it is minimal.

Comment: @PeterTaylor oh as i unterstood the op he only wanted a proof that there is no smaller period than $2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this:
If $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a function then the set of periods
$$P:=\{p\in\mathbb R\mid \forall x\in\mathbb R\colon f(x+p)=f(x)\} $$
is an ideal in the $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb R$ (i.e. sums and differences of periods are also periods).
Then $P\cap(a,b)=\emptyset$ with $a<b$ implies that $P=0$ or $P=p\mathbb Z$ for some $p\ge b-a$ (which is a more explicit way of saying that any non-principal ideal in $\mathbb R$ is dense).

Apply these facts to the sine function, about which we assume

1. $\sin\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has $2\pi$ as a period
2. $\sin x>0$ for $0<x<\pi$
3. $\sin 0 =0$
4. $\exists x\in\mathbb R\colon \sin x<0$

Then we have $P\cap(0,\pi)=\emptyset$ because $\sin(x)>0$ for $0<x<\pi$ and hence $\sin(0+x)\ne\sin(0)=0$ for such $x$.
Therefore $P=p\mathbb Z$ with $p\ge\pi$ and we have $2\pi=kp$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.
This leaves only the cases $p=\pi$ and $p=2\pi$. Since $\sin x\ge0$ for $0\le x\le\pi$, the former would imply $\sin x\ge0$ for all $x$, which is absurd.

Comment: Clarify me a thing, those assumptions, were made for the proof, but why it is needed that for the ideal, p must be greater than pi

Comment: @SebastianGriotberg One $>$ had to be replaced with $\ge$, thanks. Thus $p=\pi$ is not *immediately* excluded by checkingonly $\sin 0$ vs. $\sin p$ as of course it happens that $\sin\pi=\sin 0$. But it is excluded for many other easons - in fact conditions 2 and 3 above suffice, but we can be very specific using $\sin(\frac\pi2+\pi)=-1\ne1=\sin\frac\pi2$ if we like.